# HTML lang Attributes For Multilingual Site

Tags: html

I have a website that uses mainly English, but also incorporates a fair amount of Japanese.

What are best practices for multilingual sites? Declaring two languages in the `html` tag isn't exactly accurate, and inline `lang` markup seems redundant and heavy.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lang` attribute in the `html` element and or any element containing a sentence or more in a different language. You could count e.g. a book title or other longish phrase as a sentence. But using, say, `lang=ja` for any Japanese name occurring in English text is more or less pointless, unless you have a tangible practical reason to do so.

Language markup has several potential uses, some of which are slowly being materialized. Search engines are not known to make use of it, but e.g. automatic hyphenation (when invoked) uses it, and some speech synthesis software has used it. If you open an HTML document in Microsoft Word, it recognizes the `lang` markup and can run spell checking accordingly (for supported languages).

Such utilization of `lang` markup is most important regarding the document as a whole or major parts thereof. The more fine-grained the markup would be, the smaller its potential usefulness becomes, as a rule, in addition to being tedious to generate. It is not even clear whether e.g. a German proper name *should* be treated as German text in all respects when appearing inside English text.

Special caveat: The use of `lang` markup may affect the choice of font when left to the browser. For example, if you write `I visited <span lang=ja>Yokohama</span>`, which is logically sound (though `I visited <span lang=ja-Latn>Yokohama</span>` would be more accurate), you may well get the word “Yokohama” in a font different from the surrouding text on Firefox. The reason is that the browser uses different *default* fonts for different languages when declared in markup. But this is of course of no concern if you set the overall font family of text in CSS, as most authors do.

Answer (score 0):

> inline `lang` markup seems redundant and heavy

Well, this is the best way to do it. You can dig into the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html) if you want.